# How can I resize the Unity Facebook SDK's login dialog to fit my vertical phone screen?

Tags: unity, facebook

I have a Facebook-login button for my iOS game, but Facebook's login panel is entirely too big:

[image: Unity UI image]

The panel is cut off on both sides. It allows for input, but I cannot see most of it. My aspect ratio is 2:3; for vertical phone screens.

I tried to use `FB.Canvas.SetResolution` and `.SetAspectRatio` both did nothing. I have not attempted to view this on an iPhone yet, only in my Unity debug view.

I have never worked with Facebook SDK before, and can't find this issue discussed elsewhere, so help would be appreciated!